# How to check if an operator is invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T_1 : C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ be an operator defined by $$T_ v(x)=\int^b _a (x-t)v(t) dt$$ where $a \leq x \leq b$ and $v \in C[a.b]$

How can you check if the operator $T_1$ is invertible or not?

Comment: Are you aware that in general, taking convolution by $x^n/n!$ is equivalent to taking a $n+1$th antiderivative (here $n=1$) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K:[a,b]^2\to\mathbb R$ be the kernel defined by $K(x,t)=x-t$. Then \begin{align}
\int\limits_{[a,b]^2} |K(x,t)|^2 &=\int_a^b\int_a^b(x-t)^2\ \mathsf dx \ \mathsf dt =\frac{(b-a)^4}6 < \infty,
\end{align}
so $T_1$ is a Hilbert-Schimdt integral operator and therefore is compact. Since a compact operator on an infinite-dimensional space cannot have a bounded inverse, we conclude that $T_1$ is not invertible.